# DbContext creation into message handler

Tags: c#, simple-injector, rebus

I have a dll which exposes a type like

```
public class MyDbContext {
    [...]
}
```

inside this library I also have an `IPackage` implementation which register the `MyDbContext` in the container like

```
public void RegisterServices( Container container ) {
    container.Register<MyDbContext>( Lifestyle.Scoped );
}
```

This assembly is then referenced from two different types of applications:

- a web API project
- an asp.net MVC application

This is the initialization of the web API project

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
InitializeContainer( container );
container.RegisterWebApiControllers( GlobalConfiguration.Configuration );
container.Verify();
```

and this is the initialization of the MVC application

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
InitializeContainer( container );
container.RegisterMvcControllers( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() );
container.Verify();
```

When I receive a message from a Rebus queue (in the MVC application) the container try to instantiate a message handler like this

```
public class MyHandler : BaseMessageHandler, IHandleMessages<MyMessage>, IHandleMessages<IFailed<MyMessage>>
{
    public MyHandler( ILog logger, MyDbContext context ) {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

but I receive an error saying

> Rebus.Retry.ErrorTracking.InMemErrorTracker - Unhandled exception 1 while handling message with ID 85feff07-01a6-4195-8deb-7c8f1b62ecc3: SimpleInjector.ActivationException: The MyDbContext is registered as 'Web Request' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an active (Web Request) scope.

with the following stack trace

```
at SimpleInjector.Scope.GetScopelessInstance[TImplementation](ScopedRegistration`1 registration)
at SimpleInjector.Scope.GetInstance[TImplementation](ScopedRegistration`1 registration, Scope scope)
at SimpleInjector.Advanced.Internal.LazyScopedRegistration`1.GetInstance(Scope scope)
at lambda_method(Closure )
at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstance[TService]()
```

I have also tried to setup the Async Scoped Lifestyle in the MVC application but the error is substantially the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rebus runs your handlers on a background thread, not on a web request thread. This means that it is impossible to use the `WebRequestLifestyle` as part of the Rebus pipeline.

You should make sure that an async scope is explicitly started before a handler is executed. You can do that with a decorator/proxy.

On top of that, you should use a hybrid lifestyle for your MVC application, because MVC uses `WebRequestLifestyle` instead of `AsyncScopedLifestyle.

You can apply your hybrid lifestyle in your MVC application as follows:

```
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
    defaultLifestyle: new AsyncScopedLifestyle(),
    fallbackLifestyle: new WebRequestLifestyle());
```

Your decorator should look as follows:

```
public sealed class AsyncScopedMessageHandler<T> : IHandleMessages<T>
{
    private readonly Container container;
    private readonly Func<IHandleMessages<T>> decorateeFactory;
    public AsyncScopedMessageHandler(Container container, Func<IHandleMessages<T>> factory)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.decorateeFactory = factory;
    }
    public async Task Handle(T message) {
        using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(this.container)) {
            var decoratee = this.decorateeFactory.Invoke();
            await decoratee.Handle(message);
        }
    }
}
```

You can register your decorator as follows:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(IHandleMessages<>),
    typeof(AsyncScopedMessageHandler<>),
    Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

You should register this decorator both in MVC and your Web API project.

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for your prompt answer. Could you please clarify which modification I need to make to my MessageHandler?. Actually I simply register my handler as `container.Register<IHandleMessages<MyMessage>, MyMessageHandler>( Lifestyle.Transient )`. Should I change it?

Comment: Hi @Lorenzo, you don't have to change anything to your message handler or your registration; that's the beauty of Simple Injector combined with a well designed abstraction that Rebus provides. You just register your decorator as last decorator (if you have more) and it should just start to work.

Comment: Great quality answer .Thank you!

Comment: A small regression... after having made the suggested changes now I get a different error `System.ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.` What is this?

Comment: @Lorenzo: I'm sorry. I forgot the `await`. Please see the updated decorator.